# Convert double tuple to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I want to convert double tuple, which looks like this:

```
  {tuple}  <type 'list'>: ((u'833',), (u'765',) ,
 (u'11',) , (u'56',) , (u'61',) , (u'84',) )
```

to this string:

```
"833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84"
```

I tried this way:

```
query = double_tuple_from_above
str = ["'{}' ".format(element) for element in query ]
final_str = ', '.join(str)
# aaaa = steamids64.replace("(", "',)") # does not work
```

But the result looks not proper either way, for example like this:

```
final_str = '(u'833',)' , '(u'765',)' , '(u'11',)' , '(u'56',)' , '(u'61',)' , '(u'84',)'
```

How to flat it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

l = ["'(u'833',)' ", "'(u'765',)' ", "'(u'11',)' ", "'(u'56',)' ", "'(u'61',)' ", "'(u'84',)' "]
result = []

for elem in l:
    num = re.split(r'([0-9]+)', elem)
    result.append(num[1])

print(", ".join(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex i.e substitute non numbers with `''` using list comprehension and then join with `,`

```
import re
m = ["'(u'833',)' ", "'(u'765',)' ", "'(u'11',)' ", "'(u'56',)' ", "'(u'61',)' ", "'(u'84',)' "]
new =  ', '.join([re.sub('[^0-9]+' ,'', i) for i in m])
```

Output:

```
'833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84'
```

Answer (score 2):

your input is messed up, probably worth fixing upstream.

If you're stuck with that, use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate the tuples (after stripping the quotes & spaces from the start & end of the strings), take first item and join back to string:

```
l = ["'(u'833',)' ", "'(u'765',)' ",
 "'(u'11',)' ", "'(u'56',)' ", "'(u'61',)' ", "'(u'84',)' "]

import ast

s = ", ".join(y[0] for y in (ast.literal_eval(x.strip("' ")) for x in l))
print(s)
```

result:

```
833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex with a join:

```
import re
l = ["'(u'833',)' ", "'(u'765',)' ", "'(u'11',)' ", "'(u'56',)' ", "'(u'61',)' ", "'(u'84',)' "]

', '.join([re.search("\d+", elem).group() for elem in l if re.search("\d+", elem)])
```

This yields:

'833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84'

Answer (score 1):

Tested this in ipython. You should just need go deeper.

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Feb  4 2017, 17:39:59)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: a = ((u'833',), (u'765',), (u'11',), (u'56',), (u'61',), (u'84',))

In [2]: a
Out[2]: ((u'833',), (u'765',), (u'11',), (u'56',), (u'61',), (u'84',))

In [3]: flatter = (x[0] for x in a)

In [4]: ret = ', '.join(flatter)

In [5]: ret
Out[5]: u'833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84'

In [6]: ret = ret.encode('utf8')

In [7]: ret
Out[7]: '833, 765, 11, 56, 61, 84'
```